# Persistent query strings being passed in htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

The problem I'm having is querystrings persisting through a redirect. I.e., whenever I try and redirect a URL of type

```
RewriteRule ^oldsite/product/productname.aspx http://subdomain.newsite.com/product [L,R=301]
```

this works perfectly - no issues.

However, when I try this with anything with a querystring, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^oldsite/product/productname.aspx?=QUERYSTRING http://subdomain.newsite.com/product [L,R=301]
```

the redirect works, but I end up with the following result when I check it with a header checker:

```
http://subdomain.newsite.com/product?=QUERYSTRING
```

i.e. - it passes the querystring from the old URL, and I do not want it to.

I checked a bunch of resources but can't seem to find a simple solution to this. Is there a flag I am missing within the square parameters brackets? (Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology, new to mod_rewrite.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you append a ? to your target URL, the query string will be removed from the redirection:

```
RewriteRule ^oldsite/product/productname.aspx http://subdomain.newsite.com/product? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, query string is automatically copied over to new URL even on redirect as long as you have not done any modifications to it (e.g. new URL has no query string).

**For example:** `/register` -> `/login.php?action=register` -- the result always will be `/login.php?action=register` even if original URL would be `/register?say=bla-bla`; **but** for `/register` -> `/login.php` the query string will always be copied over, so `/register?say=bla-bla` will become `/login.php?say=bla-bla`.

**So, what needs to be done?** You need to provide some query string -- in your case the query string should be empty.

**How to do that?** Just add `?` at the end of new URL:

```
RewriteRule ^oldsite/product/productname.aspx http://subdomain.newsite.com/product? [L,R=301]
```